# Sigma notation breakdown

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, summation

What does the sum below evaluate to?
$$\sum_{i=1}^n 4^i*i $$

I know the rule for a sum of a geometric series:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n a\cdot r^{i-1}=\frac{a(r^n-1)}{r-1} $$

But I cant seeem to apply to this formula because its to the power of i
and there is also the *i factor

Comment: Do you want to know what the summation evaluates to or do you want someone to explain how to evaluate the summation term by term? Please show the work that you have done so far.

Comment: Hint: To determine the sum in closed form, consider the derivative of $f(x) = x^{i}$ at $x = 4$.

Comment: According to the title, the summation *notation* has broken down.  The question does not indicate in what way has the notation broken down.  The title should summarize what is actually going on.

Comment: @EricTowers "Breakdown is a noun that...can also mean a separation of a whole into smaller parts." That is, it could mean show the steps in a computation, or explain something in detail.  See http://www.enhancemywriting.com/breakdown-or-break-down

Comment: @Mirko : Assuming that use of the word...  That would be a "summation breakdown" or a "computation breakdown", not a "notation breakdown".  A notation breakdown would separate the notation into smaller parts, which the question is definitely not requesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such a series in which the terms are product of GP and an AP is called an AGP.

The method for evaluating such sums is simple. To determine a formula for this sum without using derivatives (as suggested in the comment) you can use the following method.

Let $$\sum_{i=1}^n 4^i*i = S$$

Or S=$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}4^{i+1}*{(i+1)} $$
Then $$4S=\sum_{i=1}^n4^{i+1}*i $$

Implies $$3S= 1+ n4^{n+1} - \sum_{i=0}^{n}4^i $$

And done.

---

EDIT:

To clarify how I got 3S, I will list S and 4S.

S= $1*4+2*4^2+3*4^3+...+n4^n$

4S=        $1*4^2+2*4^3+...+(n-1)4^n + n4^{n+1}$

On subtracting we get-

$3S= -4-4^2-4^3-...-4^n + n4^{n+1}$

Or $$3S= 1+ n4^{n+1} - \sum_{i=0}^{n}4^i $$

Comment: @Mirko yes you're right, I have definitely made a mistake. I'll check and rectify it in a minute.

Comment: @Mirko I have edited my answer. It is correct now.

Comment: @Mirko I have made a typo. The indices of the last summation should be from 0 to n, not 1 to n. This time I'm hundred percent sure I have made no mistake (at least I hope).

Comment: I hope it is right ... it produces the correct answer for $n=1, n=2$ and $n=3$ can't be a coincidence ...

Comment: Could you explain how 4S actually implies 3S, can't seem to follow what happens. Thanks for your input btw

Comment: @DinoDan see the edit.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{i=1}^n 4^i*i $$ means that sum all the terms from $i=1$ to $i=n$.

So:

$\sum_{i=1}^n 4^i*i =4^1* (1)+4^2* (2)+4^3* (3)+...…+4^n* (n)$ so add all terms one by one until you reach $n$ while replacing $i$ by the term number.

Answer (score 2):

The formula $3S= 1+ n4^{n+1} - \sum_{i=0}^{n}4^i$ (where $S=\sum_{i=1}^n 4^i\cdot i$) from @Random-15's answer simplifies to
$$S=\frac{(3n-1)4^{n+1}+4}9$$ which does produce correct answers $4, 36$ and $228$ for $n=1,2,3,$ respectively.

Now, knowing the formula let me try to prove it by induction.

When $n=1$ we have $\sum_{i=1}^1 4^i\cdot i = 4^1\cdot1=4$ and 
$\frac{(3\cdot1-1)4^{1+1}+4}9=\frac{(2)4^2+4}9=\frac{36}9=4$, so the formula 
$S=\frac{(3n-1)4^{n+1}+4}9$ is correct when $n=1$.

Assume formula is correct for some $n\ge1$. Prove it for $n+1$. We have 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} 4^i\cdot i=\sum_{i=1}^n 4^i\cdot i +4^{n+1}\cdot(n+1)=$$ (by induction hypothesis)
$$=\frac{(3n-1)4^{n+1}+4}9+4^{n+1}\cdot(n+1)= 
\frac{(3n-1+9n+9)4^{n+1}+4}9=$$ 
$$=\frac{(12n+12-4)4^{n+1}+4}9=\frac{4(3n+3-1)4^{n+1}+4}9=$$
$$=\frac{\bigl(3(n+1)-1\bigr)4^{n+2}+4}9$$ which completes the proof.

Note. Wolfram alpha also gives a similar formula:
$\sum_{i=1}^n 4^i\cdot i = \frac49 (3\cdot 4^n\cdot n - 4^n + 1)$.